# Fabric.JS sizing guidelines

Tags: fabricjs

I've been trying to add sizing guidelines for my app built on FabricJS. I see the library provides guidelines for alignment and centering but not for sizing. I did some search on the web and I was not able to find it. I also tried to create it but I could not.

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/centering_guidelines.js

So, if you know a library that does that or if you can point me out a direction I appreciate. Thanks in advance.